# Replacing String Pattern with C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace string matching specific pattern using C# regular expression. I did try out various regular expression with Regex.Replace Function but none of them worked for me. Can anyone help me build correct regex to replace part of string.

Here is my input string. Regex should match string that starts with `<message Severity="Error">Password will expire in 30 days` then any characters (even new lines characters) till it finds closing `</message>` tag. If regex finds matching pattern then it should replace it with empty string.

Input String :

```
<message Severity="Error">Password will expire in 30 days.
Please update password using following instruction.
1. login to abc
2. change password.
</message>
```

Comment: Regex tends to be a poor choice for parsing XML. I suggest using an XML parser like `XDocument` instead.

Comment: what did your `Regex.Replace` functions look like? and what happened when you ran them?

Comment: I understand but we need to strip out message based on runtime configuration which is provided in regex format.

Comment: If you are trying to ignore a specific error, this is at the wrong layer.  Do it in the application layer after you've already converted the XML into usable objects.

Comment: it also looks like you're having some newline troubles

Comment: I don't have good knowledge on Regular expression but i tried out following which not helping <message Severity="Error">Password will expire in 30 days.(.*?)</message>

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said in comments - `XML` parsing may be better suited. Also - this might not be the best solution, depending on what you're trying to achieve. but here's passing unit test - you should be able to make sens of it.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    string input = "<message Severity=\"Error\">Password will expire in 30 days.\n"
                    +"Please update password using following instruction.\n"
                    +"1. login to abc\n"
                    +"2. change password.\n"
                    +"</message>";
    input = "something other" + input + "something else";

    Regex r = new Regex("<message Severity=\"Error\">Password will expire in 30 days\\..*?</message>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    input = r.Replace(input, string.Empty);

    Assert.AreEqual<string>("something othersomething else", input);
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, but please take some advises from other answers as well - it might be better to pick better approach than regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LINQ2XML` but if you want `regex`

```
<message Severity="Error">Password will expire in 30 days.*?</message>(?s)
```

OR

In linq2Xml

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXml.xml");

foreach(var elm in doc.Descendants("message"))
{
    if(elm.Attribute("Severity").Value=="Error")
        if(elm.Value.StartsWith("Password will expire in 30 days"))
        {
            elm.Remove();
        }
}
doc.Save("yourXml");\\don't forget to save :P
```

Answer (score 2):

I know there are objections to the approach, but this works for me. (I suspect you were probably missing the RegexOptions.SingleLine, which will allow the dot to match newlines.)

```
string input = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<message Severity=\"Error\">Password will    expire in 30 days.\nPlease update password using following instruction.\n"
        + "1. login to abc\n\n2. change password.\n</message>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <message>another message</message>";

string pattern = @"<message Severity=""Error"">Password will expire in 30 days.*?</message>";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

//result = "lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet <message>another message</message>"
```